# What is a Cinderella attack

Tags: attacks

I've read online that it is a time-based attack, but not much other information was given. Can someone explain the definition of a Cinderella attack to me?

Answer (score 6):

Cinderella attack: A cyber-attack that disables security software by manipulating the network internal clock time so a security software license expires prematurely rendering the target network vulnerable to cyber-attack.

Extracted from the book: [Cybersecurity Lexicon](https://books.google.es/books?id=rrW4DAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=cyber+security+lexicon&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia4Jjy58LTAhXDCBoKHaEcCxYQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=cyber%20security%20lexicon&f=false)

Comment: the carriage turns into a pumpkin at midnight...